# How to have apache handle .well-known/acme-challenge and still have / passed to wsgi

Tags: apache2, django, lets-encrypt, wsgi

In order to support automatic LetsEncrypt certificate renewal certbot uses the ***--apache*** handler.

e.g.

```
certbot renew --apache
```

This handler installs a temporary VirtualHost for ***/.well-known/acme-challenge/** on the Apache server in order authenticate the renewal.

The problem is that this mechanism does not work if the existing virtual server uses HTTPS and Django over WSGI mounted on the http server root.

The temporary VirtualHost fails to capture the URL and so Django tries to service the request (and fails) as the URL is not in it's list of URLs.

Comment: I do not have Django or WSGI, but I do have multiple URL's being served from the same host. I do not know whether that's the issue, but Apache 2.4 **refuses** to serve up any file or directory deeper than ".well-known". I have been unable to find any Apache configuration that fixes that. Your answer below of "tricking" Apache into serving something aliased to ".well-known" worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing the question made me think about how it works, so I then worked out the answer. As I could not find an answer to what must be a common issue I thought I'd post what I have found.

There are other solutions, E.g. [certbot-django](https://pypi.org/project/certbot-django/) and [django-letsencrypt](https://pypi.org/project/django-letsencrypt/) but both are fare more hastle than just letting the stock certbot handle it.

The ***--apache*** certbot handler places it's files in ***/var/lib/letsencrypt/http_challenges***, so all that is required is to have Apache handle those files in the same way as the docs recommend for static files.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    [....SSL stuff]

    AliasMatch /.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*)$ /var/lib/letsencrypt/http_challenges/$1
    <directory /var/lib/letsencrypt/http_challenges>
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
    </directory>

    [....WSGI stuff]
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/myserver/myapp/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is the first solution after days of research that finally worked.

Comment: Why don't you tag this as the Answer to your Question?

Comment: @UncaAlby  Lol, I did not know you could give yourself a green tick!

Comment: Oh yes, in fact, no mater who answers the question, even if it's you, it's your *responsibility* to flag it as the acceptable answer so people searching for that question will know it's been answered!